# xpath evaluator expression for generic middle path

Tags: xpath

```
/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/fxOption/fxVanillaOption/option/optionStyle

/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/fxOption/**fxBarrierOption/fxOption**/fxVanillaOption/option/optionStyle

/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/fxOption/**fxSwapOption/fxOption**/fxVanillaOption/option/optionStyle
```

I am looking for a general expression for the various xpath. Though the beginning and end parts are always identical.
Is this the correct XPath?

```
/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/fxOption*//*fxVanillaOption/option/optionStyle
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but you had a few extra asterisks and slashes. Try this:

```
/MxML/trades/trade/tradeBody/fxOption/*/fxVanillaOption/option/optionStyle
```